# Twitter DropDown - Getting Triggered by Icon rather than Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two icons from font icons, and I am trying to assign them to bootstrap's dropdown, to put append notifications in it.

```
  <li class="col-md-offset-0" style="list-style-type: none">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: right; height: 70px">
        <li style="margin-top: 9px; padding-right: 35px" data-toggle="dropdown">
             <span class="customIconSet" style="font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer">m</span>
        </li>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu right">
             <li><a href="#">AA</a></li>
         </ul>
         <li style="margin-top: 1px; padding-right: 15px" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span class="customIconSet" style="font-size: 25px; cursor: pointer">n</span>
         </li>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu right">
              <li><a href="#">BB</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
   </li>
```

However, I have two problems.

1) The dropdown gets created in the left side of the screen where the icons are located on the right side. So forms completely irrelevant to where it pops.

2) It opens BB dropdown even when I click on the other icon triggering the dropdown. At the same time, it feels like BB is holding a bigger area (like a hidden div) so that seems like the reason.

Edit: [Here is a fiddle on bootply](http://www.bootply.com/9ESlh41BT1).
Problem 1 doesn't happen in this example but 2 happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have a couple of ul's directly inside a ul that is invalid syntax, if they are meant to be part of one of the li's you need to move them inside those tags

Comment: @PatrickEvans just added a fiddle to show my problem more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

http://www.bootply.com/mBFRyBTJG4

I changed a some of the formatting to fit the normal bootstrap dropdown formatting, something more along the lines of:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
Dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

By ensuring they are correctly formatted and have individual id's you should be able to have the correct dropdown open for each item.

Comment: It works perfectly in bootply but when I copied and adapted your code into mine, second dropdown doesn't open (BB), even when the html is changing. (These 2 are changing: `<li class="dropdown open"` and `aria-expanded: true/false`)

Comment: If you copy and paste your code back into bootply does it?